# How can map reduce be used in javascript to summarize information in a multi-layer nested object?

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, mapreduce

I'm trying to write a function which will efficiently summarize data from a series of nested javascript objects. I believe that this should be do-able with the reduce method but am not very proficient at using reduce and almost all of the examples I can find are using nested arrays or some combination of arrays and objects while my data is coming solely as a series of nested objects (and is more deeply nested than the examples I can find.

Here's my raw data:

```
var activity = {
    "Network": {
      "ID": "Network",
      "MLS": {
        "ID": "MLS",
        "Ports": {
          "ID": "Ports",
          "GigabitEthernet0/1": {
            "ID": "GigabitEthernet0/1",
            "Port Mode": {
              "ID": "Port Mode",
              "Name": "Port Mode",
              "Value": "0",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 8
            },
            "Native VLAN": {
              "ID": "Native VLAN",
              "Name": "Native VLAN",
              "Value": "99",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 5
            }
          },
          "GigabitEthernet0/2": {
            "ID": "GigabitEthernet0/2",
            "IP Address": {
              "ID": "IP Address",
              "Name": "IP Address",
              "Value": "209.165.200.225",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 0
            },
            "Subnet Mask": {
              "ID": "Subnet Mask",
              "Name": "Subnet Mask",
              "Value": "255.255.255.252",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 0
            },
            "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {
              "ID": "Ipv6 Address",
              "2001:DB8:ACAD:A::1": {
                "ID": "2001:DB8:ACAD:A::1",
                "IP Address": {
                  "ID": "IP Address",
                  "Name": "IP Address",
                  "Value": "2001:DB8:ACAD:A::1",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                },
                "Prefix Length": {
                  "ID": "Prefix",
                  "Name": "Prefix Length",
                  "Value": "64",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                }
              }
            },
            "SwitchPort": {
              "ID": "SwitchPort",
              "Name": "SwitchPort",
              "Value": "0",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 8
            }
          },
          "Vlan10": {
            "ID": "Vlan10",
            "IP Address": {
              "ID": "IP Address",
              "Name": "IP Address",
              "Value": "192.168.10.254",
              "PointsPossible": 2,
              "PointsEarned": 2,
              "ComparatorClass": 0
            },
            "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {
              "ID": "Ipv6 Address",
              "2001:DB8:ACAD:10::1": {
                "ID": "2001:DB8:ACAD:10::1",
                "IP Address": {
                  "ID": "IP Address",
                  "Name": "IP Address",
                  "Value": "2001:DB8:ACAD:10::1",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                },
                "Prefix Length": {
                  "ID": "Prefix",
                  "Name": "Prefix Length",
                  "Value": "64",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "Vlan20": {
            "ID": "Vlan20",
            "IP Address": {
              "ID": "IP Address",
              "Name": "IP Address",
              "Value": "192.168.20.254",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 0
            },
            "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {
              "ID": "Ipv6 Address",
              "2001:DB8:ACAD:20::1": {
                "ID": "2001:DB8:ACAD:20::1",
                "IP Address": {
                  "ID": "IP Address",
                  "Name": "IP Address",
                  "Value": "2001:DB8:ACAD:20::1",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                },
                "Prefix Length": {
                  "ID": "Prefix",
                  "Name": "Prefix Length",
                  "Value": "64",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "Vlan30": {
            "ID": "Vlan30",
            "IP Address": {
              "ID": "IP Address",
              "Name": "IP Address",
              "Value": "192.168.30.254",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 0
            },
            "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {
              "ID": "Ipv6 Address",
              "2001:DB8:ACAD:30::1": {
                "ID": "2001:DB8:ACAD:30::1",
                "IP Address": {
                  "ID": "IP Address",
                  "Name": "IP Address",
                  "Value": "2001:DB8:ACAD:30::1",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                },
                "Prefix Length": {
                  "ID": "Prefix",
                  "Name": "Prefix Length",
                  "Value": "64",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "Vlan99": {
            "ID": "Vlan99",
            "IP Address": {
              "ID": "IP Address",
              "Name": "IP Address",
              "Value": "192.168.99.254",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 0
            }
          }
        },
        "Routes": {
          "ID": "Routes",
          "Static Routes": {
            "ID": "Static RoutesV2",
            "Name": "Static Routes",
            "Value": "",
            "PointsPossible": 0,
            "PointsEarned": 0,
            "ComparatorClass": 1
          },
          "IP Routing": {
            "ID": "IP Routing",
            "Name": "IP Routing",
            "Value": "1",
            "PointsPossible": 1,
            "PointsEarned": 1,
            "ComparatorClass": 1
          }
        },
        "Routesv6": {
          "ID": "Routesv6",
          "IPv6 Unicast Routing": {
            "ID": "Ipv6 Unicast Routing",
            "Name": "IPv6 Unicast Routing",
            "Value": "1",
            "PointsPossible": 1,
            "PointsEarned": 1,
            "ComparatorClass": 1
          }
        },
        "VLANS": {
          "ID": "VLANS",
          "VLAN 10": {
            "ID": "10",
            "VLAN Name": {
              "ID": "VLAN Name",
              "Name": "VLAN Name",
              "Value": "Staff",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 5
            }
          },
          "VLAN 20": {
            "ID": "20",
            "VLAN Name": {
              "ID": "VLAN Name",
              "Name": "VLAN Name",
              "Value": "Student",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 5
            }
          },
          "VLAN 30": {
            "ID": "30",
            "VLAN Name": {
              "ID": "VLAN Name",
              "Name": "VLAN Name",
              "Value": "Faculty",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 5
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "S1": {
        "ID": "S1",
        "Ports": {
          "ID": "Ports",
          "GigabitEthernet0/1": {
            "ID": "GigabitEthernet0/1",
            "Port Mode": {
              "ID": "Port Mode",
              "Name": "Port Mode",
              "Value": "0",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 8
            },
            "Native VLAN": {
              "ID": "Native VLAN",
              "Name": "Native VLAN",
              "Value": "99",
              "PointsPossible": 2,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 5
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

I am looking to summarize the data as a whole (totalPointsEarned, totalPointsPossible, totalItemsPossible, totalItemsComplete) as well as by each "ComparatorClass", though that should be stored by name instead of by number. The mapping from ComparatorClass numbers to names looks like:

```
    var comparatorClassIdToNameMap = {
        0:"Ip",
        1:"Routing",
        2:"Acl",
        3:"Nat",
        4:"Physical",
        5:"Switching",
        6:"Connectivity",
        7:"Logical",
        8:"All",
        9:"Encircling_Head",
        10:"Encircling_All"
    };
```

So the final result should look something like this:

```
{
  "totalPointsEarned": 25,
  "totalPointsPossible": 26,
  "totalItemsComplete": 24,
  "totalItemsPossible": 24,
  "Ip": {
    "pointsEarned": 7,
    "pointsPossible": 7,
    "itemsComplete": 6,
    "itemsPossible": 6,
    "ComparatorClassID": 0
  },
  "Routing": {
    "pointsEarned": 2,
    "pointsPossible": 2,
    "itemsComplete": 2,
    "itemsPossible": 2,
    "ComparatorClassID": 1
  },
  "Acl": {
    "pointsEarned": 0,
    "pointsPossible": 0,
    "itemsComplete": 0,
    "itemsPossible": 0,
    "ComparatorClassID": 2
  },
  "Nat": {
    "pointsEarned": 0,
    "pointsPossible": 0,
    "itemsComplete": 0,
    "itemsPossible": 0,
    "ComparatorClassID": 3
  },
  "Physical": {
    "pointsEarned": 0,
    "pointsPossible": 0,
    "itemsComplete": 0,
    "itemsPossible": 0,
    "ComparatorClassID": 4
  },
  "Switching": {
    "pointsEarned": 5,
    "pointsPossible": 6,
    "itemsComplete": 5,
    "itemsPossible": 5,
    "ComparatorClassID": 5
  },
  "Connectivity": {
    "pointsEarned": 0,
    "pointsPossible": 0,
    "itemsComplete": 0,
    "itemsPossible": 0,
    "ComparatorClassID": 6
  },
  "Logical": {
    "pointsEarned": 0,
    "pointsPossible": 0,
    "itemsComplete": 0,
    "itemsPossible": 0,
    "ComparatorClassID": 7
  },
  "All": {
    "pointsEarned": 0,
    "pointsPossible": 0,
    "itemsComplete": 0,
    "itemsPossible": 0,
    "ComparatorClassID": 8
  },
  "Encircling_Head": {
    "pointsEarned": 0,
    "pointsPossible": 0,
    "itemsComplete": 0,
    "itemsPossible": 0,
    "ComparatorClassID": 9
  },
  "Encircling_All": {
    "pointsEarned": 0,
    "pointsPossible": 0,
    "itemsComplete": 0,
    "itemsPossible": 0,
    "ComparatorClassID": 10
  }
}
```

The pointsEarned/pointsPossible are just summed from the raw data, the itemsComplete is a count of each leaf which has > 0 pointsEarned and the itemsPossible is a count of each leaf which has > 0 pointsPossible.

Any assistance in how I might use reduce to efficiently calculate these values (or some other method) would be appreciated. I could figure it out with a series of for/ifs but that seems incredibly inefficient.

Thanks!

Comment: how are data combined together?

Comment: If examples are in a different format.. have you thought about map to transform and reduce to aggregate, chaining the two together to yield the result you are after?

Comment: please add some data, pattern and result who match.

Comment: I believe the original question did include how the data are combined as well as sample data. I have updated the question to include what I believe is accurate sample result values. Hopefully this is more clear!

Comment: just for example how does `'Routing'` gets the wanted counts? where is the origin in your raw data?

Comment: The data originates from a network tree scoring model in the Cisco Packet Tracer software. The ```Routing``` output is from the original ```activity``` object where the ```ComparatorClassID == 1``` In this case that includes three leaf nodes ```Routes```, ```IP Routing```, and ```Routesv6``` two of which contain ```PointsPossible > 0``` so two itemsPossible, etc.

Comment: What is the source of `itemsComplete` and `itemsPossible`?

Comment: ```itemsComplete``` would be a count of any nodes in the tree (matching the particular ComparatorClassID) where the ```pointsEarned``` is > 0. ```itemsPossible``` would be a count of any nodes in the tree (matching the particular ComparatorClassID) where the ```pointsPossible``` is > 0.  Think of it as an exam where each question is categorized (ComparatorClassID) and has some number of points assigned to it. We're counting the number of points in each category as well as totally that are possible as well as the number of questions that are possible in each category and totally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

After I wrote the solutions below, I realized that this really could be done more simply in exactly the way you suggested, mapping, then reducing the result.  It's not precisely mapping, more of an extraction of the leaves.  But then we can convert your `comparatorClassIdToNameMap` to an initial output object and simply reduce those leaves into it.

While the below is not beautiful code, it does solve the problem in the manner you requested, which is more than I can say for the solutions I first wrote.

```js
// utility function
const findLeaves = (isLeaf) => (obj) =>
  isLeaf (obj) 
    ? [obj]
    : Object .values (obj) .flatMap (
        (v) => typeof v == 'object' ? findLeaves (isLeaf) (v) : []
      )

// main function
const transform = (actvity, nameMapping) => findLeaves (obj => 'PointsPossible' in obj) (activity) 
  .reduce((
    {totalPointsPossible, totalPointsEarned, ...rest}, 
    {PointsPossible, PointsEarned, ComparatorClass},
    _, __,  // index and array passed to `reduce` are ignored
    {PointsPossible: pp, PointsEarned: pe} = rest[nameMapping[ComparatorClass]]
  ) => ({                                                              // line 7
      totalPointsPossible: totalPointsPossible + PointsPossible,
      totalPointsEarned: totalPointsEarned + PointsEarned,
      ...rest,
      [nameMapping[ComparatorClass]]: {
        PointsPossible: PointsPossible + pp,
        PointsEarned: PointsEarned + pe,
        ComparatorClassId: ComparatorClass
      }
    }),                                                                 // line 16
    Object.entries(comparatorClassIdToNameMap).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({ // line 17
      ... a,
      [v]: {
        PointsPossible: 0,
        PointsEarned: 0,
        ComparatorClassId: Number(k)
      }
    }), {totalPointsPossible: 0, totalPointsEarned: 0})                 // line 24
  )


// data
const activity = {Network: {ID: "Network", MLS: {ID: "MLS", Ports: {ID: "Ports", "GigabitEthernet0/1": {ID: "GigabitEthernet0/1", "Port Mode": {ID: "Port Mode", Name: "Port Mode", Value: "0", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 8}, "Native VLAN": {ID: "Native VLAN", Name: "Native VLAN", Value: "99", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}, "GigabitEthernet0/2": {ID: "GigabitEthernet0/2", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "209.165.200.225", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Subnet Mask": {ID: "Subnet Mask", Name: "Subnet Mask", Value: "255.255.255.252", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {ID: "Ipv6 Address", "2001: DB8: ACAD: A: : 1": {ID: "2001: DB8: ACAD: A: : 1", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "2001: DB8: ACAD: A: : 1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Prefix Length": {ID: "Prefix", Name: "Prefix Length", Value: "64", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}, SwitchPort: {ID: "SwitchPort", Name: "SwitchPort", Value: "0", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 8}}, Vlan10: {ID: "Vlan10", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "192.168.10.254", PointsPossible: 2, PointsEarned: 2, ComparatorClass: 0}, "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {ID: "Ipv6 Address", "2001: DB8: ACAD: 10: : 1": {ID: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 10: : 1", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 10: : 1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Prefix Length": {ID: "Prefix", Name: "Prefix Length", Value: "64", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}}, Vlan20: {ID: "Vlan20", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "192.168.20.254", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {ID: "Ipv6 Address", "2001: DB8: ACAD: 20: : 1": {ID: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 20: : 1", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 20: : 1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Prefix Length": {ID: "Prefix", Name: "Prefix Length", Value: "64", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}}, Vlan30: {ID: "Vlan30", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "192.168.30.254", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {ID: "Ipv6 Address", "2001: DB8: ACAD: 30: : 1": {ID: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 30: : 1", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 30: : 1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Prefix Length": {ID: "Prefix", Name: "Prefix Length", Value: "64", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}}, Vlan99: {ID: "Vlan99", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "192.168.99.254", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}, Routes: {ID: "Routes", "Static Routes": {ID: "Static RoutesV2", Name: "Static Routes", Value: "", PointsPossible: 0, PointsEarned: 0, ComparatorClass: 1}, "IP Routing": {ID: "IP Routing", Name: "IP Routing", Value: "1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 1}}, Routesv6: {ID: "Routesv6", "IPv6 Unicast Routing": {ID: "Ipv6 Unicast Routing", Name: "IPv6 Unicast Routing", Value: "1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 1}}, VLANS: {ID: "VLANS", "VLAN 10": {ID: "10", "VLAN Name": {ID: "VLAN Name", Name: "VLAN Name", Value: "Staff", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}, "VLAN 20": {ID: "20", "VLAN Name": {ID: "VLAN Name", Name: "VLAN Name", Value: "Student", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}, "VLAN 30": {ID: "30", "VLAN Name": {ID: "VLAN Name", Name: "VLAN Name", Value: "Faculty", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}}}, S1: {ID: "S1", Ports: {ID: "Ports", "GigabitEthernet0/1": {ID: "GigabitEthernet0/1", "Port Mode": {ID: "Port Mode", Name: "Port Mode", Value: "0", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 8}, "Native VLAN": {ID: "Native VLAN", Name: "Native VLAN", Value: "99", PointsPossible: 2, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}}}}};
const comparatorClassIdToNameMap = {0: "Ip", 1: "Routing", 2: "Acl", 3: "Nat", 4: "Physical", 5: "Switching", 6: "Connectivity", 7: "Logical", 8: "All", 9: "Encircling_Head", 10: "Encircling_All"}

// demo
console .log (
  transform (activity, comparatorClassIdToNameMap)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Lines 17 - 24 create an initial object with all the properties you want in your output, using `comparatorClassIdToNameMap` and adding the `total*` properties.

Lines 7 - 14 adds a leaf node into that.  This happens inside a `reduce`, and so all leaf nodes are added and the resulting object is returned.

### Addendum

A comment said that you're not well-versed in JS.  Here is an alternate version of the function above, written in an ES5 style.  This one may be easier to read for those coming from other mainstream languages:

```js
function transform (actvity, nameMapping) {
  var baseObj = {totalPointsPossible: 0, totalPointsEarned: 0}
  
  for (var id in nameMapping) {
    if (nameMapping .hasOwnProperty (id)) {
      var name = nameMapping [id]
      baseObj [name] = {
        PointsPossible: 0,
        PointsEarned: 0,
        ComparatorClassId: Number(id)
      }
    }
  }
  
  function isLeaf(obj) {
    return 'PointsPossible' in obj
  }
  
  var leaves = findLeaves (isLeaf) (activity)

  return leaves .reduce (
    function (acc, item) {
      acc .totalPointsPossible += item .PointsPossible
      acc .totalPointsEarned += item .PointsEarned
      var key = nameMapping [item .ComparatorClass]
      acc [key] .PointsPossible += item .PointsPossible
      acc [key] .PointsEarned += item .PointsEarned
      return acc
    },
    baseObj
  )
}
```

This one does exactly the same thing as above.  But it is filled with assignment, mutation, and control-flow statements, all things I personally try to avoid.  The version above avoids all that by using destructuring and other more modern techniques.

### Addendum 2

This converts `findLeaves` to ES5, by shimming `Object.prorotype.flatMap` and `Object.values` with ES5 tools and replacing arrow functions with function expressions:

```js
const values = function (obj) { 
  return Object .keys (obj) .map (k => obj [k])
}

const flatMap = function (fn) { 
  return function (xs) { 
    return xs .reduce ((a, x) => a .concat (fn (x)), [])
  }
}

const findLeaves = function (isLeaf) {
  return function(obj) {
    return isLeaf (obj) 
      ? [obj]
      : flatMap (
          (v) => typeof v == 'object' ? findLeaves (isLeaf) (v) : []
        ) (values (obj))
  }
}
```

---

## Original Solution

*I no longer recommend either of the following two suggestions, but I think there might still be value in them.*

### Using a library

I'm a big fan of the functional programming library [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) (disclaimer: I'm one of its main authors), and I often see such problems through Ramda's eyes.  So first, a solution that uses a Ramda fairly heavily:

```js
// utility function
const findLeaves = (isLeaf) => (obj) =>
  isLeaf (obj) 
    ? [obj]
    : Object .values (obj) .flatMap (
        (v) => typeof v == 'object' ? findLeaves (isLeaf) (v) : []
      )

// helper functions
const summarize = pipe (
  findLeaves (has('PointsPossible')),
  groupBy (prop ('ComparatorClass')),
  map ( applySpec ({
    PointsPossible: pipe (pluck ('PointsPossible'), sum),
    PointsEarned: pipe (pluck ('PointsEarned'), sum),
    ComparatorClassID: pipe (head, prop ('ComparatorClass'))
  }))
)

  
const extractTotals = (activity, nameMapping, summary = summarize(activity)) =>
  reduce (
    (a, [id, name]) => 
      ({...a, [name]: summary [id] || 
      {PointsPossible: 0, PointsEarned: 0, ComparatorClassID: id}}), 
    {},
    toPairs (nameMapping)
  )

// main function  
const transform = (activity, nameMapping, totals = extractTotals (activity, nameMapping)) => 
  Object .assign (applySpec ({
    totalPointsPossible: pipe (pluck ('PointsPossible'), sum),
    totalPointsEarned: pipe (pluck ('PointsEarned'), sum),
  }) (values (totals)), totals)

// data
const activity = {Network: {ID: "Network", MLS: {ID: "MLS", Ports: {ID: "Ports", "GigabitEthernet0/1": {ID: "GigabitEthernet0/1", "Port Mode": {ID: "Port Mode", Name: "Port Mode", Value: "0", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 8}, "Native VLAN": {ID: "Native VLAN", Name: "Native VLAN", Value: "99", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}, "GigabitEthernet0/2": {ID: "GigabitEthernet0/2", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "209.165.200.225", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Subnet Mask": {ID: "Subnet Mask", Name: "Subnet Mask", Value: "255.255.255.252", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {ID: "Ipv6 Address", "2001: DB8: ACAD: A: : 1": {ID: "2001: DB8: ACAD: A: : 1", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "2001: DB8: ACAD: A: : 1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Prefix Length": {ID: "Prefix", Name: "Prefix Length", Value: "64", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}, SwitchPort: {ID: "SwitchPort", Name: "SwitchPort", Value: "0", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 8}}, Vlan10: {ID: "Vlan10", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "192.168.10.254", PointsPossible: 2, PointsEarned: 2, ComparatorClass: 0}, "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {ID: "Ipv6 Address", "2001: DB8: ACAD: 10: : 1": {ID: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 10: : 1", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 10: : 1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Prefix Length": {ID: "Prefix", Name: "Prefix Length", Value: "64", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}}, Vlan20: {ID: "Vlan20", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "192.168.20.254", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {ID: "Ipv6 Address", "2001: DB8: ACAD: 20: : 1": {ID: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 20: : 1", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 20: : 1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Prefix Length": {ID: "Prefix", Name: "Prefix Length", Value: "64", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}}, Vlan30: {ID: "Vlan30", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "192.168.30.254", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {ID: "Ipv6 Address", "2001: DB8: ACAD: 30: : 1": {ID: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 30: : 1", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 30: : 1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Prefix Length": {ID: "Prefix", Name: "Prefix Length", Value: "64", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}}, Vlan99: {ID: "Vlan99", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "192.168.99.254", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}, Routes: {ID: "Routes", "Static Routes": {ID: "Static RoutesV2", Name: "Static Routes", Value: "", PointsPossible: 0, PointsEarned: 0, ComparatorClass: 1}, "IP Routing": {ID: "IP Routing", Name: "IP Routing", Value: "1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 1}}, Routesv6: {ID: "Routesv6", "IPv6 Unicast Routing": {ID: "Ipv6 Unicast Routing", Name: "IPv6 Unicast Routing", Value: "1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 1}}, VLANS: {ID: "VLANS", "VLAN 10": {ID: "10", "VLAN Name": {ID: "VLAN Name", Name: "VLAN Name", Value: "Staff", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}, "VLAN 20": {ID: "20", "VLAN Name": {ID: "VLAN Name", Name: "VLAN Name", Value: "Student", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}, "VLAN 30": {ID: "30", "VLAN Name": {ID: "VLAN Name", Name: "VLAN Name", Value: "Faculty", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}}}, S1: {ID: "S1", Ports: {ID: "Ports", "GigabitEthernet0/1": {ID: "GigabitEthernet0/1", "Port Mode": {ID: "Port Mode", Name: "Port Mode", Value: "0", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 8}, "Native VLAN": {ID: "Native VLAN", Name: "Native VLAN", Value: "99", PointsPossible: 2, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}}}}};
const comparatorClassIdToNameMap = {0: "Ip", 1: "Routing", 2: "Acl", 3: "Nat", 4: "Physical", 5: "Switching", 6: "Connectivity", 7: "Logical", 8: "All", 9: "Encircling_Head", 10: "Encircling_All"}

// demo
console .log (
  transform (activity, comparatorClassIdToNameMap)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script>
const {pipe, has, groupBy, prop, map, applySpec, pluck, sum, head, reduce, toPairs, values} = R
</script>
```

Our main `transform` function depends on `extractTotals`, which depends on `summarize`, which in turn depends on `findLeaves`.  Obviously, as `extractTotals` and `summarize` are used internally only, you could internalize them within one another; I wouldn't recommend it.  And `findLeaves` is recursive so can't be handled that way.

`findLeaves` takes a predicate function to test whether a node is a leaf and an object and recursively finds all the nodes that are reported to be leaves.  It doesn't handle arrays, but that wasn't part of your requirements; it would not be hard to extend if needed.

If we call `findLeaves(obj => 'PointsPossible' in obj)(activity)`, we get a flat array containing all the leaf nodes, like this:

```js
[
    {
        "ID": "Port Mode",
        "Name": "Port Mode",
        "Value": "0",
        "PointsPossible": 1,
        "PointsEarned": 1,
        "ComparatorClass": 8
    },
    {
        "ID": "Native VLAN",
        "Name": "Native VLAN",
        "Value": "99",
        "PointsPossible": 1,
        "PointsEarned": 1,
        "ComparatorClass": 5
    },
    // ...
]
```

`summarize` uses `findLeaves` and a number of Ramda functions to turn your `activity` into

```js
{
    "0": {
        "PointsPossible": 15,
        "PointsEarned": 15,
        "ComparatorClassID": 0
    },
    "1": {
        "PointsPossible": 2,
        "PointsEarned": 2,
        "ComparatorClassID": 1
    },
    // ...
}
```

We get almost all the way there with `extractTotals`, which combines the above with your `comparatorClassIdToNameMap` to get this:

```js
{
    "Ip": {
        "PointsPossible": 15,
        "PointsEarned": 15,
        "ComparatorClassID": 0
    },
    "Routing": {
        "PointsPossible": 2,
        "PointsEarned": 2,
        "ComparatorClassID": 1
    },
    // ...
}
```

The only thing missing is the overall totals.  That is left for `transform`, which takes the result of the above and adds the these totals to the resulting object:

```js
{
    "totalPointsPossible": 26,
    "totalPointsEarned": 25,
    "Ip": {
        "PointsPossible": 15,
        "PointsEarned": 15,
        "ComparatorClassID": 0
    },
    "Routing": {
        "PointsPossible": 2,
        "PointsEarned": 2,
        "ComparatorClassID": 1
    },
    // ...
}
```

(**Note** that there is nothing here to handle your `itemsComplete` or `itemsPossible`.  I see nothing in the data to help with that, but I'm guessing would be simple extensions to the above.)

This breakdown of the problem is my usual technique of doing small transformations one at a time always trying to move toward the required solution.  There might be useful ways to combine steps.  I leave that to you.

### Without a library

There is no magic involved in a library like Ramda.  We can write reusable versions of its functions on our own.  And doing so will often improve many parts of our code.

So, we could do this same breakdown on our own, by writing custom version of these Ramda functions.  Most are trivial.  Only `applySpec`, `groupBy` and `mapObj` have any complexity.  Note that in the Ramda version above, we used Ramda's `map` in place of `mapObj` here.  While we could write `map` to handle either arrays or objects, here it's simpler to just make two functions.

```js
// utility functions
const pipe = (...fns) => (arg) => 
  fns.reduce((a, fn) => fn(a), arg) 
const map = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs .map (x => fn (x))
const mapObj = (fn) => (obj) => 
  Object .fromEntries (map (([k, v]) => [k, fn (v)]) (Object .entries (obj)))
const has = (name) => (obj) => 
  name in obj
const prop = (name) => (obj) =>
  obj [name]
const pluck = (name) => 
  map (prop (name))
const head = (xs) => 
  xs [0]
const sum = (ns) =>
  ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)
const applySpec = (spec) => (obj) =>
  Object .entries (spec) .reduce ((a, [k, fn]) => ({...a, [k]: fn (obj)}), {})
const groupBy = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((a, x, _, __, k = fn(x)) => ({...a, [k]: [...(a[k] || []), x]}), {})

const findLeaves = (isLeaf) => (obj) =>
  isLeaf (obj) 
    ? [obj]
    : Object .values (obj) .flatMap (
        (v) => typeof v == 'object' ? findLeaves (isLeaf) (v) : []
      )

// helper functions
const summarize = pipe (
  findLeaves (has ('PointsPossible')),
  groupBy (prop ('ComparatorClass')),
  mapObj ( applySpec ({
    PointsPossible: pipe (pluck ('PointsPossible'), sum),
    PointsEarned: pipe (pluck ('PointsEarned'), sum),
    ComparatorClassID: pipe (head, prop ('ComparatorClass'))
  }))
)

const extractTotals = (activity, nameMapping, summary = summarize(activity)) =>
  Object .entries (nameMapping)
    .reduce (
      (a, [id, name]) => ({...a, [name]: summary[id] || {PointsPossible: 0, PointsEarned: 0, ComparatorClassID: id}}), 
      {}
    )

// main function
const transform = (activity, nameMapping) => {
  const totals = extractTotals (activity, nameMapping)
  return Object .assign (applySpec ({
    totalPointsPossible: pipe (pluck ('PointsPossible'), sum),
    totalPointsEarned: pipe (pluck ('PointsEarned'), sum),
  }) (Object .values (totals)), totals)
}

// data
const activity = {Network: {ID: "Network", MLS: {ID: "MLS", Ports: {ID: "Ports", "GigabitEthernet0/1": {ID: "GigabitEthernet0/1", "Port Mode": {ID: "Port Mode", Name: "Port Mode", Value: "0", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 8}, "Native VLAN": {ID: "Native VLAN", Name: "Native VLAN", Value: "99", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}, "GigabitEthernet0/2": {ID: "GigabitEthernet0/2", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "209.165.200.225", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Subnet Mask": {ID: "Subnet Mask", Name: "Subnet Mask", Value: "255.255.255.252", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {ID: "Ipv6 Address", "2001: DB8: ACAD: A: : 1": {ID: "2001: DB8: ACAD: A: : 1", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "2001: DB8: ACAD: A: : 1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Prefix Length": {ID: "Prefix", Name: "Prefix Length", Value: "64", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}, SwitchPort: {ID: "SwitchPort", Name: "SwitchPort", Value: "0", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 8}}, Vlan10: {ID: "Vlan10", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "192.168.10.254", PointsPossible: 2, PointsEarned: 2, ComparatorClass: 0}, "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {ID: "Ipv6 Address", "2001: DB8: ACAD: 10: : 1": {ID: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 10: : 1", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 10: : 1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Prefix Length": {ID: "Prefix", Name: "Prefix Length", Value: "64", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}}, Vlan20: {ID: "Vlan20", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "192.168.20.254", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {ID: "Ipv6 Address", "2001: DB8: ACAD: 20: : 1": {ID: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 20: : 1", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 20: : 1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Prefix Length": {ID: "Prefix", Name: "Prefix Length", Value: "64", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}}, Vlan30: {ID: "Vlan30", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "192.168.30.254", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {ID: "Ipv6 Address", "2001: DB8: ACAD: 30: : 1": {ID: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 30: : 1", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "2001: DB8: ACAD: 30: : 1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}, "Prefix Length": {ID: "Prefix", Name: "Prefix Length", Value: "64", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}}, Vlan99: {ID: "Vlan99", "IP Address": {ID: "IP Address", Name: "IP Address", Value: "192.168.99.254", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 0}}}, Routes: {ID: "Routes", "Static Routes": {ID: "Static RoutesV2", Name: "Static Routes", Value: "", PointsPossible: 0, PointsEarned: 0, ComparatorClass: 1}, "IP Routing": {ID: "IP Routing", Name: "IP Routing", Value: "1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 1}}, Routesv6: {ID: "Routesv6", "IPv6 Unicast Routing": {ID: "Ipv6 Unicast Routing", Name: "IPv6 Unicast Routing", Value: "1", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 1}}, VLANS: {ID: "VLANS", "VLAN 10": {ID: "10", "VLAN Name": {ID: "VLAN Name", Name: "VLAN Name", Value: "Staff", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}, "VLAN 20": {ID: "20", "VLAN Name": {ID: "VLAN Name", Name: "VLAN Name", Value: "Student", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}, "VLAN 30": {ID: "30", "VLAN Name": {ID: "VLAN Name", Name: "VLAN Name", Value: "Faculty", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}}}, S1: {ID: "S1", Ports: {ID: "Ports", "GigabitEthernet0/1": {ID: "GigabitEthernet0/1", "Port Mode": {ID: "Port Mode", Name: "Port Mode", Value: "0", PointsPossible: 1, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 8}, "Native VLAN": {ID: "Native VLAN", Name: "Native VLAN", Value: "99", PointsPossible: 2, PointsEarned: 1, ComparatorClass: 5}}}}}};
const comparatorClassIdToNameMap = {0: "Ip", 1: "Routing", 2: "Acl", 3: "Nat", 4: "Physical", 5: "Switching", 6: "Connectivity", 7: "Logical", 8: "All", 9: "Encircling_Head", 10: "Encircling_All"}

// demo
console .log (
  transform (activity, comparatorClassIdToNameMap)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This uses the same breakdown of the problem as above, simply writing custom version of the Ramda functions.  If you want to find out more about any of them (except `mapObj`, which in Ramda is covered by `map`), please see the [Ramda documentation](https://ramdajs.com/docs/).  These implementation are simpler than Ramda's, and are generally less flexible, but they work for our cases.

## Note

I found this an interesting problem to try.  But I almost gave up immediately because of the wall of data.  It's very difficult to scroll through that much data to try to discern the requirements.  Next time, please review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.  You should be able to make a much smaller test case that still demonstrates the goal.

Comment: Thanks, I'm probably going to be accepting your latest answer but I want to make sure I fully understand it first, especially given that JavaScript is not my strongest language and there's a lot going on there. It will probably take me a few days to get back to this and sort though an understanding of what's going on.

Comment: @BenFranske: Feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: @BenFranske: I added an addendum to the updated answer with an ES5 version, one which may feel more familiar.

Comment: Sorry, I have been off on more pressing work until recently when I've had a chance to get back to this. Thanks for the ES5 version, that makes more sense. I actually need to implement in ES5 syntax anyway as this is going into a Qt Script plugin in an application and the newer syntax is not supported. Also, it makes more sense to me.  Unfortunately it looks like there are still a couple things that seem to be in newer syntax and I don't understand quite how they are working. Specifically, the findLeaves utility function and the call to that function in the transform function. Help appreciated.

Comment: @BenFranske: added another addendum converting the `isLeaf` function.  As far as I can see, the call to it shouldn't need to change.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means pretty (5 nested forEach loops) and needs cleaned up. but the basic premise is there and should get you where you need to go.

```js
const comparatorClassIdToNameMap = {
      0:"Ip",
      1:"Routing",
      2:"Acl",
      3:"Nat",
      4:"Physical",
      5:"Switching",
      6:"Connectivity",
      7:"Logical",
      8:"All",
      9:"Encircling_Head",
      10:"Encircling_All"
  }, activity = {
    "Network": {
      "ID": "Network",
      "MLS": {
        "ID": "MLS",
        "Ports": {
          "ID": "Ports",
          "GigabitEthernet0/1": {
            "ID": "GigabitEthernet0/1",
            "Port Mode": {
              "ID": "Port Mode",
              "Name": "Port Mode",
              "Value": "0",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 8
            },
            "Native VLAN": {
              "ID": "Native VLAN",
              "Name": "Native VLAN",
              "Value": "99",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 5
            }
          },
          "GigabitEthernet0/2": {
            "ID": "GigabitEthernet0/2",
            "IP Address": {
              "ID": "IP Address",
              "Name": "IP Address",
              "Value": "209.165.200.225",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 0
            },
            "Subnet Mask": {
              "ID": "Subnet Mask",
              "Name": "Subnet Mask",
              "Value": "255.255.255.252",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 0
            },
            "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {
              "ID": "Ipv6 Address",
              "2001:DB8:ACAD:A::1": {
                "ID": "2001:DB8:ACAD:A::1",
                "IP Address": {
                  "ID": "IP Address",
                  "Name": "IP Address",
                  "Value": "2001:DB8:ACAD:A::1",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                },
                "Prefix Length": {
                  "ID": "Prefix",
                  "Name": "Prefix Length",
                  "Value": "64",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                }
              }
            },
            "SwitchPort": {
              "ID": "SwitchPort",
              "Name": "SwitchPort",
              "Value": "0",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 8
            }
          },
          "Vlan10": {
            "ID": "Vlan10",
            "IP Address": {
              "ID": "IP Address",
              "Name": "IP Address",
              "Value": "192.168.10.254",
              "PointsPossible": 2,
              "PointsEarned": 2,
              "ComparatorClass": 0
            },
            "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {
              "ID": "Ipv6 Address",
              "2001:DB8:ACAD:10::1": {
                "ID": "2001:DB8:ACAD:10::1",
                "IP Address": {
                  "ID": "IP Address",
                  "Name": "IP Address",
                  "Value": "2001:DB8:ACAD:10::1",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                },
                "Prefix Length": {
                  "ID": "Prefix",
                  "Name": "Prefix Length",
                  "Value": "64",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "Vlan20": {
            "ID": "Vlan20",
            "IP Address": {
              "ID": "IP Address",
              "Name": "IP Address",
              "Value": "192.168.20.254",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 0
            },
            "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {
              "ID": "Ipv6 Address",
              "2001:DB8:ACAD:20::1": {
                "ID": "2001:DB8:ACAD:20::1",
                "IP Address": {
                  "ID": "IP Address",
                  "Name": "IP Address",
                  "Value": "2001:DB8:ACAD:20::1",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                },
                "Prefix Length": {
                  "ID": "Prefix",
                  "Name": "Prefix Length",
                  "Value": "64",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "Vlan30": {
            "ID": "Vlan30",
            "IP Address": {
              "ID": "IP Address",
              "Name": "IP Address",
              "Value": "192.168.30.254",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 0
            },
            "(deprecated) IPv6 Addresses": {
              "ID": "Ipv6 Address",
              "2001:DB8:ACAD:30::1": {
                "ID": "2001:DB8:ACAD:30::1",
                "IP Address": {
                  "ID": "IP Address",
                  "Name": "IP Address",
                  "Value": "2001:DB8:ACAD:30::1",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                },
                "Prefix Length": {
                  "ID": "Prefix",
                  "Name": "Prefix Length",
                  "Value": "64",
                  "PointsPossible": 1,
                  "PointsEarned": 1,
                  "ComparatorClass": 0
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "Vlan99": {
            "ID": "Vlan99",
            "IP Address": {
              "ID": "IP Address",
              "Name": "IP Address",
              "Value": "192.168.99.254",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 0
            }
          }
        },
        "Routes": {
          "ID": "Routes",
          "Static Routes": {
            "ID": "Static RoutesV2",
            "Name": "Static Routes",
            "Value": "",
            "PointsPossible": 0,
            "PointsEarned": 0,
            "ComparatorClass": 1
          },
          "IP Routing": {
            "ID": "IP Routing",
            "Name": "IP Routing",
            "Value": "1",
            "PointsPossible": 1,
            "PointsEarned": 1,
            "ComparatorClass": 1
          }
        },
        "Routesv6": {
          "ID": "Routesv6",
          "IPv6 Unicast Routing": {
            "ID": "Ipv6 Unicast Routing",
            "Name": "IPv6 Unicast Routing",
            "Value": "1",
            "PointsPossible": 1,
            "PointsEarned": 1,
            "ComparatorClass": 1
          }
        },
        "VLANS": {
          "ID": "VLANS",
          "VLAN 10": {
            "ID": "10",
            "VLAN Name": {
              "ID": "VLAN Name",
              "Name": "VLAN Name",
              "Value": "Staff",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 5
            }
          },
          "VLAN 20": {
            "ID": "20",
            "VLAN Name": {
              "ID": "VLAN Name",
              "Name": "VLAN Name",
              "Value": "Student",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 5
            }
          },
          "VLAN 30": {
            "ID": "30",
            "VLAN Name": {
              "ID": "VLAN Name",
              "Name": "VLAN Name",
              "Value": "Faculty",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 5
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "S1": {
        "ID": "S1",
        "Ports": {
          "ID": "Ports",
          "GigabitEthernet0/1": {
            "ID": "GigabitEthernet0/1",
            "Port Mode": {
              "ID": "Port Mode",
              "Name": "Port Mode",
              "Value": "0",
              "PointsPossible": 1,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 8
            },
            "Native VLAN": {
              "ID": "Native VLAN",
              "Name": "Native VLAN",
              "Value": "99",
              "PointsPossible": 2,
              "PointsEarned": 1,
              "ComparatorClass": 5
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
toActivityObjectsArr(activity);

function toActivityObjectsArr (obj) {
  const arr = [], searchKey = 'ComparatorClass';
  Object.keys(obj.Network).forEach(function (networkChild) {
    Object.keys(obj.Network[networkChild]).forEach(function (networkGrandChild) {
      networkGrandChild == searchKey && arr.push(obj.Network[networkChild]);
      Object.keys(obj.Network[networkChild][networkGrandChild]).forEach(function (networkGreatGrandChild) {
        networkGreatGrandChild == searchKey && arr.push(obj.Network[networkChild][networkGrandChild]);
        Object.keys(obj.Network[networkChild][networkGrandChild][networkGreatGrandChild]).forEach(function (networkGreatGreatGrandChild) {
          networkGreatGreatGrandChild == searchKey && arr.push(obj.Network[networkChild][networkGrandChild][networkGreatGrandChild]);
          Object.keys(obj.Network[networkChild][networkGrandChild][networkGreatGrandChild][networkGreatGreatGrandChild]).forEach(function (networkGreatGreatGreatGrandChild) {
            networkGreatGreatGreatGrandChild == searchKey && arr.push(obj.Network[networkChild][networkGrandChild][networkGreatGrandChild][networkGreatGreatGrandChild]);
            Object.keys(obj.Network[networkChild][networkGrandChild][networkGreatGrandChild][networkGreatGreatGrandChild][networkGreatGreatGreatGrandChild]).forEach(function (networkGreatGreatGreatGreatGrandChild) {
              networkGreatGreatGreatGreatGrandChild == searchKey && arr.push(obj.Network[networkChild][networkGrandChild][networkGreatGrandChild][networkGreatGreatGrandChild][networkGreatGreatGreatGrandChild]);
              Object.keys(obj.Network[networkChild][networkGrandChild][networkGreatGrandChild][networkGreatGreatGrandChild][networkGreatGreatGreatGrandChild][networkGreatGreatGreatGreatGrandChild]).forEach(function (networkGreatGreatGreatGreatGreatGrandChild) {
                networkGreatGreatGreatGreatGreatGrandChild == searchKey && arr.push(obj.Network[networkChild][networkGrandChild][networkGreatGrandChild][networkGreatGreatGrandChild][networkGreatGreatGreatGrandChild][networkGreatGreatGreatGreatGrandChild]);
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
  createAnswerObj(arr);
}
function createAnswerObj(arr) {
  const answerObj = {};
  answerObj.totalPossiblePoints = getTotalPossiblePoints(arr);
  answerObj.totalPointsEarned = getTotalPointsEarned(arr);
  Object.keys(comparatorClassIdToNameMap).forEach(function (k) {
    answerObj[comparatorClassIdToNameMap[k]] = {
      pointsEarned: getPointsEarnedByComparator(arr, k),
      pointsPossible: getPointsPossibleByComparator(arr, k),
      ComparatorClassID: k
    };
  });
  console.log(answerObj);
}
function getTotalPossiblePoints(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (total, obj) {
    return total += obj.PointsPossible;
  }, 0);
}
function getPointsPossibleByComparator(arr, k) {
  return arr.reduce(function (total, obj) {
    return obj.ComparatorClass == k ? (total += obj.PointsPossible) : total;
  }, 0);
}
function getTotalPointsEarned(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (total, obj) {
    return total += obj.PointsEarned;
  }, 0);
}
function getPointsEarnedByComparator(arr, k) {
  return arr.reduce(function (total, obj) {
    return obj.ComparatorClass == k ? (total += obj.PointsEarned) : total;
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was something along the lines of what I was hoping to avoid. I think your answer could even be cleaned up and better generalized with some recursion but I think it should actually be doable with a recursive map/reduce function which would be even cleaner and faster but am not quite sure how to do that which is really the basis of my question.